# Debugging of Internet Explorer 9-10 crash

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I'm a new developer of one site. Previous developer left a lot of trash and unstable code. But the main problem is that when I open this website and try to navigate throught the pages (just try 1-2 links) it crashes my IE 9-10. 
**After I open the page, IE freezes completly, I can't do anything in it.**

My question is:

How can I track the problem (may be some kind of debugger or online emulator)? Can you recommend some software or online tool to track JS/HTML errors, which can I use to understand the crash reason?

Comment: Well there's the debugger built into the browser, for starters.

Comment: After I open the page, IE freezes completly, I can't do anything in it.

Comment: Comment out scripts and start reneabling them one by one until you find out which one causes the problem. Go into that file and comment out chunks until you pinpoint an area where the problem happens.

Comment: Yes, this is good advise, the only problem that this can spare a lot of time..

Comment: @magalter Can you update us on progress? What ended up being the problem?

Comment: The problem was in AJAX response and its position on page. If AJAX popup is big enough and doesn't fit to page height, it may crash IE. Unfortunatly, I have no time to reproduce problem on clean page. Seems that it is some kind of IE bug. The fix was to move html from AJAX popup higher, so it can fit to page height fully.

Answer (score 13):

Good question!

So! Your website crashes in IE, it's a painful problem I've had some times before. It's no fun, and don't expect a silver bullet solution, take comfort in that you're not the first one to experience this problem.

[You can use visual studio to debug IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx). Visual Studio lets you run specific script statements, use breakpoints and run specific bits of code in Internet Explorer.

If that seems too extreme to you, [IE comes bundled with developer tools.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) However, I doubt that would be any help if IE crashes your site. Chances are, it'll crash even faster with developer tools open.

Here are some tips for debugging code that crashes your browser:

- [Disable JavaScript](http://browsers.about.com/od/internetexplorertutorials/ss/disable-javascript-ie9.htm) does the persist? If it does remove resources one by one.
- If disabling JavaScript solves your issue, start enabling script files one by one. (Send the others to fake urls. Track the one file that's giving you the problem.
- Use `alert` statements, they're **blocking** so no code is run in the background while they work (unless using things like WebWorkers), they don't require any extra tools, while they're messy, they're the most reliable thing you can do. You can put them in the middle of your DOM and they'll block the dom for rendering allowing you to spot exactly where the problem is.
- Add Synchronous AJAX calls, while usually I'm strictly against abusing AJAX like this, you can write a small logger on your server that accepts these calls and logs. This will let you use logging.
- Know where to ask! A good resource for asking IE specific odd questions that even good resources like StackOverflow can't solve is the [IE Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/). The IE developer team reply to comments there, and you can ask questions like "why doesn't my site work" directly.
- Don't forget to open a bug report when you find the problem! You'd want developers to do the same for you.

Comment: @magalter I will not give you the fish, the idea is to teach you how to fish :) Chances are IE will crash sites you work on in the future too. Learning to do this sort of tedious debugging process with `alert` statements, disabling scripts and such is important. Once you get good at it it becomes less painful. It's also educational because it forces you to write modular code, and heavily unit, and integration test your code. I was in your position before, having to fix stuff in broken code that doesn't run in IE, it sucks, but working with it effectively made me a better developer.

Comment: That's a great answer. I'll point colleagues to it when needed.

Comment: The problem is that IE dies completely (*IE freezes completly, I can't do anything in it.). So I can't make alerts, etc in it. I can just disable JS fully (comment all code) and then uncomment parts and track if IE will not die. This is I'm doing now :)

Comment: What I'm saying, is that instead of commenting all scripts and uncommenting them one by one which would take O(n) time, you can put a `<script type="text/javascript">i=0</script>` at the top of the head section, and then  `<script type='text/javascript'> alert(i++)</script>` between each script tag, this would take O(1) time of debugging instead of O(n) since you'd get which script is the problem in one shot.